# Powerpoint ppEffectPageTurn available?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Sub ppEffectPageTurn()
    Dim slide As slide
    Dim transitionTime As Single

    transitionTime = 0.5

    For Each slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        slide.SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect = ppEffectPageTurn
        slide.SlideShowTransition.AdvanceOnTime = msoTrue
        slide.SlideShowTransition.AdvanceTime = transitionTime
    Next slide
End Sub
```

ppt page turning animation

Comment: `EntryEffect` takes a [PpEntryEffect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppentryeffect) Enum member as its value ... the Docs do not include `ppEffectPageTurn` so I guess the answer to your question is 'No' ... however, on my device with PowerPoint 365, the Docs do not include all the Enum members I have available on my device (eg `ppEffectPageCurlDoubleLeft`) ... hence my answer isn't definitive.

Comment: MS' docs usually lag behind whatever the current version offers. For this kind of thing, it's often more useful to check the Object Browser (press F2 in the VBA IDE). Look up ppEntryEffect, scroll down and find ppEffectPageCurlDoubleLeft, DoubleRight, SingleLeft and SingleRight. Click the one you want to see its numeric value below.